# onclick event to call javascript prototype function

Tags: javascript, class, onclick, prototype

Is it possible to do something like this inside a class:

```
<a href="javascript:" onclick="this.remove(id, name)">Remove</a>
```

in order to call this:

```
myclass.prototype.remove = function(id, name){
    //do stuff
}
```

? Currently my remove function is outside the class on its own, but I need it to be able to access and manipulate the configuration settings array that exists inside the class.

Comment: See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Comment: Does this work when the anchor tags are dynamically generated after doc ready?

Comment: Yes, you can use event delegation.

Comment: Do you have a myclass instance for every anchor?

Comment: No, the anchors are generated based on multiple file selections from a input type=file element. So their IDs are auto generated too, making document.getElementbyID() tricky for me.

Comment: Oh wait. Well yeah, each file in the array iterates through the class functions, if that counts.